# Saving multiple Mongoose objects with asyncjs not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I want to save two Mongoose objects in my mocha test - and be notified when both have succeeded. I am using the asyncjs library to achieve this.

```
beforeEach (done) ->

  obj1 = new Person({ name: 'Jon' })
  obj2 = new Person({ name: 'Dan' })

  console.log obj1   # ... { name: 'Jon', _id: 4534534543512 }

  async.list([
    obj1.save
    obj2.save
  ]).call().end( (err, res) ->
    return done(err) if err
    done()
  )
```

You can see that obj1 is being set to a MongoDB document in the console.log - but when I want to persist them to the db using the save function, I get the following error when trying to execute this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined
```

If I were to replace the two functions in the async.list with say

```
console.log
console.log
```

The code executes fine ... Also, if I were to save the two objects outside the async.list function like so

```
obj1.save()
obj2.save()
```

It too executes fine with no errors.

I am stumped.

Comment: Also worth noting, is that there are two similarly named async libraries: async, and asyncjs. The above example is from asyncjs - but the better library is async, and the method to use there instead is: parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely because the `save` functions aren't being called with a expected context (`this`).

When you pass a "*method*" like `obj1.save`, the reference `async.list()` gets is only to the `function` itself without any link back to `obj1` (or `obj2`). It would be similar to:

```
save = obj1.save
save() # `this` is `undefined` or `global`
```

To pass with a fixed context, you can either [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) them:

```
async.list([
  obj1.save.bind(obj1)
  obj2.save.bind(obj2)
]) # etc.
```

Or use additional functions so they're called after a [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators):

```
async.list([
  (done) -> obj1.save(done),
  (done) -> obj2.save(done)
]) # etc.
```

Comment: That did the trick - thank you - you put an end to a lot of frustration. I suspected something around _this_ - and passed this in via the call method - and called this.obj1.save(), which clearly didn't work.